# Was the Mishna Brurah meant to be learned straight?

Tags: halacha, torah-study, halacha-theory, mishnah-berurah

Disclaimer - I do not intend to dispute common practices in Klal Yisroel, nor do I intend to criticize the incredible work of an incredible Talmid Chacham.

The current practice in a considerable number of communities is to learn Halacha by going through the Mishna Brurah. I have always wondered if that was the intention of the Chofetz Chaim when he wrote it, and there are some things that I have noticed that make me wonder. For example, there are times where he refers to what he wrote a few lines earlier in the same seif, which logically the reader would have seen going straight through. Another thing I have noticed is that the MB does not always give a clear cut psak (see MB 311:3 compared to Be'er Hetev and Aruch Hashulchan there).

Was the MB meant to be learned straight through and to be used for psak Halacha, or is it some time of explanation to help a person navigate the Shulchan Aruch?

Comment: Good question. I was always wondering if Rashi has an "order" on Shas (where if there's a sugya later that repeats an earlier sugya, he doesn't explain it twice)

Comment: @ShmuelBrin: Rashi doesn't seem to be consistent with that. Sometimes he'll note that the Gemara will ask a question, even though that is the *immediately* following question, and sometimes seems to have relied on your reading through a whole section.

Comment: To add evidence to the likelihood that he didnt intend it to be used as comprehensively is his own divergent practices from MB. These include his cup that wasnt the shiur, his tucked in tzitzis (although his grandchildren say he recanted), and his using less than his shiur of matza.

Comment: yes, read about it in hakdomeh

Comment: @havarka I wasn't 100% clear on what he meant by calling the MB a ביאור especially in light of the places where he does not come to a clear conclusion.

Comment: I was told once that there are those that don't rely on the MB, but rather on the *Aruch Hashulchan* since the latter was a *rov* of a city whereas the former was not.

Answer (score 6):

The Mishnah Berurah explains his purview in his introduction.* He notes that there are two problems preventing people from properly learning halacha from the Shulchan Aruch:

1) It is almost impossible to understand the Shulchan Aruch on its own without the background from the Tur/Beis Yosef but no one has time to properly go through a sugya in this fashion.

> אחת כי השלחן ערוך לבדו בלתי למוד הטור הוא כספר החתום כי הבית יוסף
>   כשסדר השלחן ערוך היה דעתו שילמדו מתחלה את עקרי הדינים ומקוריהם בטור
>   ובית יוסף כדי שיתישב הדין לכל אחד בדעתו בטעמו ונמוקו אך לאשר שבטור
>   ובית יוסף נמצא לפעמים כמה דעות חלוקין בכל דין ודין לכך ערך לפנינו את
>   שלחנו הטהור לידע הלכה למעשה בכל דין ודין אבל לא היה דעתו שנלמד אותו
>   בלחוד כי אין הדין יוכל להתישב היטב בדעת האדם כל זמן שאין יודעו בטעמו
>   ונמוקו וגם על ידי ידיעת הטעמים נפקא מנה כמה פעמים למעשה כי כמה פעמים
>   נתחבר בשלחן ערוך בסעיף אחד דבר שהוא רק לכתחלה ודבר שהוא לעכובא אף
>   בדיעבד גם דבר שהוא מדאורייתא ודבר שהוא מדרבנן ונפקא מנה לענין ספק
>   וכהאי גונא עוד כמה ענינים עצומים בכל סימן וסימן אשר לא יתברר לאדם כי
>   אם על ידי ידיעת טעמיהם וללמד כל דין ודין שבשלחן ערוך במקורו וטעמו מן
>   הטור ובית יוסף יכבד זה בזמננו מאד על האדם כי בעונותינו הרבים נתמעטו
>   הלבבות וגם הטרדות נתגברו מאד אשר אם ירצה האדם בלמוד כזה לידע על נכון
>   סימן אחד בינוני למעשה יצטרך לעמל בו כמה ימים ולפעמים כמה שבועות כמו
>   סימן ל"ב וכדומה אם לא מי שחננו ה' שיש לו לב רחב ואין לו שום טרדה

2) There are so many differences of opinion among the acharonim subsequent to the Shulchan Aruch that one needs to search through to arrive at a final halachic conclusion, and no one has time to go through each sugya in this fashion either.

> סבה שניה שגרם למעט למוד השלחן ערוך לדעתי הוא מפני שכבד הדבר מאד לידע
>   ממנו הדין למעשה מפני התחלקות רב הדעות המובא באחרונים ואין האדם יודע
>   איך לפנות את עצמו לימין או לשמאל וכאשר ירצה האדם תמיד להחמיר בדבר גם
>   זה איננו דרך כבושה כי פעמים רבות הוא חומרא דאתי לידי קולא עוד ראיתי
>   והתבוננתי כי מעת שלקט וקצר הבאר היטב את דברי הט"ז ומגן אברהם ועוד
>   מפרשים ותשובות שקדמוהו עד עתה הוא לערך מאה ושלשים שנה ומאותו העת עד
>   עתה רבו כמו רבו כמה גאונים מפרסמים מפרשי השלחן ערוך אליה רבה ומטה
>   יהודא ומאמר מרדכי ורבות כהנה וגם בשערי תשובה לא הובא מהם כי אם מעט
>   מזער באיזה מקומות ובפרט ספר הפרי מגדים אשר הוא ספר נכבד מאד אשר בו
>   מבאר בכל סימן וסימן ענינים מחדשים למעשה ונתפשט הוראותיו בישראל לא נזכר
>   כמעט בכל השערי תשובה כל  כי מפני רבוי ספרי השו"ת שהיה מטל עליו להעתיק
>   לא העתיק ממפרשי שלחן ערוך המצויין כמעט כלל וסמך על המעין בם גם הרבה
>   והרבה גאונים מפרסמים אשר נתפשט דבריהם בעולם אחר הדפסת השערי תשובה כמו
>   הגאון רבי עקיבא איגר ודרך החיים ומגן גבורים וארצות החיים וכדומה זאת
>   ועוד אחרת ראיתי בעני ועמל ישראל כי עתה כשנצרך האדם לידע איזה דין למעשה
>   שאין מברר היטב בשלחן ערוך הוא מכרח לחפש בכמה וכמה מהאחרונים בפרי מגדים
>   ודרך החיים וחדושי רבי עקיבא איגר וחיי אדם ומחצית השקל ורבות כהנה ואין
>   קץ לעמלו

In short, the issue is that in order to properly learn Shulchan Aruch you have to also learn everything (slight exaggeration) that came before and after it as well, which is only feasible for a select few individuals.

The Mishnah Berurah claims to be the solution to this problem. It will essentially do the work for you. It will provide the necessary background so that you don't have to learn all the pre-Shulchan Aruch stuff, and it will provide a survey of the acharonim, and a conclusion that is apparently based on the consensus of acharonim barring certain other factors (for instance the extra weight of the Gra's opinion or a proof from the rishonim), so that you don't have to learn all the post-Shulchan Aruch stuff. Obviously, this is not absolute and it may vary throughout the Mishnah Berurah – there may well be instances where it doesn't provide all the background or doesn't give a final ruling – but this was the general purpose/goal.

> אשר על כן נתעוררתי ונתחזקתי בחסדי השם יתברך לתקן את כל אלה כי עשיתי
>   בעזרת השם יתברך באור מספיק לדעתי על שלחן ערוך הזה עד אחר הלכות תפלה
>   לעת עתה ^ וקראתי שמו משנה ברורה ובו בארתי בעזרת השם יתברך את כל דין
>   ודין שבשלחן ערוך בטעמו ונמוקו מגמרא ופוסקים אשר לא יהיה כספר החתום גם
>   בארתי בו במקום שנמצא דעות בין הפוסקים את מסקנת האחרונים להלכה על כל
>   דין (והבאור ההוא מלוקט מב"ח ודרישה ופרישה ואליהו רבה ובאור הגר"א ופרי
>   מגדים וברכי יוסף ומאמר מרדכי ומטה יהודא ונהר שלום ודגול מרבבה ובאר
>   היטב ושערי תשובה ושלחן ערוך של הגר"ז ולבושי שרד ושלחן שלמה ודרך החיים
>   וחדושי רבי עקיבא איגר וישועת יעקב וחיי אדם ומחצית השקל ומגן גבורים
>   וארצות החיים ורבות כהנה וגם מכמה ספרי שו"ת   וארצות החיים ורבות כהנה
>   וגם מכמה ספרי שו"ת) ובשולי היריעה פתחתי שער ושמו שער הציון בו צינתי על
>   כל דבר שבתוך המשנה ברורה כדי לידע מבטן מי יצאו הפנינים האלו ובמקום
>   שראיתי דעות בין שני אחרונים גופא באיזה דבר לא הייתי עצל בדבר מלחפש
>   בכלל ספרי שאר אחרונים לראות אל מי מקדושים דעתם פונה למעשה ובפרט בבאור
>   הגר"א ז"ל שהוא אורן של ישראל ויתד שהכל תלוי בו וכדאי להכריע הדבר גם
>   חפשתי בספרי ראשונים אולי אמצא בם הדבר מפרש או שאר ראיה ברורה כי ברוך
>   השם יש לי הרבה ספרי ראשונים

That being said, there doesn't seem to be any reason why its use should be limited to either learning straight through, or to helping you understand a particular part of the Shulchan Aruch. If you are learning straight through then the "final ruling" part might be more useful to you, while if you are seeking clarification on a specific issue the "background explanation" part might be more useful. The fact that it might refer back to something recently stated does not indicate that it was not meant to be read straight through; it merely helps someone who hasn't read it straight through (or forgot something even so recent).

*Also explained in brief on the title page.

Comment: Another excellent and clear answer.  I read the question and immediately thought that I'll just quote his introduction, but you beat me to it. (In fact, I never would have seen the question if not for you answering it, so that's an unfair statement on my part.  Oh well.)

Comment: _and it will provide a survey of the acharonim, and a consensus ruling_ Maybe I just missed it in the above quote, but I don't see him claiming that he will provide a "consensus ruling", if by that you mean the MB's conclusion based on the literature. What he does say is that it is hard to  practically know what to do without the relevant sources laid out in front of you. || This distinction is particularly relevant given that the OP specifically differentiated between whether it is meant to be used as its own pesak work, or whether it is merely meant to guide study through the sources.

Comment: @mevaqesh The part that I actually quoted was only the discussion of the problems. I didn't quote the discussion of the solution where this is mentioned; I just summarized it. But I will edit the answer to clarify.